# One-liner to create dictionary of lists

Tags: python

how to do this list/dict comprehension 
turn this `[("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3)]`

into  this

```
{
  "a": [1, 3],
  "b": [2]
}
```

I know how to do it in a for loop, can I use just one line to do the work?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a simple `defaultdict(list)` and a loop here.  It's fast, it's readable

Comment: Do you believe that the single line will be easier to maintain than the for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a simple [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3)]

items = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in lst:
    items[k].append(v)

print(items)
```

Which creates:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2]})
```

**Note:** If you want the final result to be a normal dictionary, you can just wrap `dict()`.

If you really want a one liner, you could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in a dict comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3)]
>>> {k: list(map(itemgetter(1), g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2]}
```

Which can also be written more cleanly as:

```
{k: [x[1] for x in g] for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}
```

The above solution has `O(NlogN)` complexity due to sorting, a requirement if you want to group similar items together. This is less efficient than  The first `defaultdict` solution, which is `O(N)`, since you only need to iterate the list once. The first solution would be more preferable, since its easier to read, efficient and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think using a loop is a simple option here, but for the sake of demonstration, you can define a custom class here that inherits from **`collections.MutableMapping`** to accomplish your goal.

```
import collections

class AutoListDict(collections.MutableMapping):

  def __init__(self, values=()):            
      self.inner = collections.defaultdict(list)
      for k, v in values:
          self[k].append(v)

  def __setitem__(self, k, v): self.inner[k] = v
  def __getitem__(self, k):return self.inner[k]
  def __delitem__(self, k_): del self.inner[k]
  def __iter__(self): return iter(self.inner)
  def __len__(self): return len(self.inner)
  def __repr__(self): return str(dict(self.inner))
```

This initializes a **`defaultdict`** from your input values, so instead of overwriting a key it appends to it.  In action, you can simply call the class constructor on your array of tuples:

```
>>> arr = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
>>> AutoListDict(arr)
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2]}
```

Or if you want something more similar to a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> dct = AutoListDict((k, v) for k, v in arr)
>>> dct
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2]}
```